# Win32 Main Message Loop for OpenGL

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, waitformultipleobjects

My main message loop in a Win32 OpenGL application looks like this:

```
// Inside wWinMain
bool bQuit = false;
while( bQuit == false )
{
    DWORD dwReturn = ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects( 0, NULL, FALSE, 12, QS_ALLINPUT );

    if( dwReturn == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
    {
        MSG msg;
        BOOL bReturn = ::PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE );
        if( bReturn != FALSE )
        {
            if( msg.message == WM_QUIT )
                bQuit = true;
            ::TranslateMessage( &msg );
            ::DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    }

    if( dwReturn == WAIT_OBJECT_0 || dwReturn == WAIT_TIMEOUT )
    {
        RenderFrame();
        ::SwapBuffers( hDc );
    }
}
```

It works almost fine, I have only one problem: if I press Alt+F4 to close the window, it does not quit right after I release the key, however, if I hover the mouse over the window, it quits instantly.

A) Why is this? How should I modify my loop?

B) The original code I found did not use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects but called RenderFrame continuously. I think this way too much CPU time is wasted on redrawing the screen. Am I right? What is the usual way, do you spend all your excess capacity on drawing?

Comment: Please show real code. Your `while( bQuit )` loop never runs.

Comment: Doesn't look like we have sufficient code. And this code isn't real. The loop will never execute.

Comment: @IInspectable - how about `if( msg.message == WM_QUIT ) bQuit = true;` ? this and break loop

Comment: B) How often you want to draw depends on what you draw. If you draw animations, then you will need at least 30fps to get it smooth. If you write a game, then input-display latency might be a point and you will want to update the view as often as you can (or at least at the refresh rate of the monitor, but that whats vsync is for).

Comment: look like call `PeekMessage` *only once* but not in loop `while(PeekMessage)` very common error with `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` code - i view this error already not first time

Comment: I just wanted to simplify the code, sorry for the error, I corrected it: bQuit is true initially.

Comment: @z32a7ul - may be `bool bQuit = false; while( !bQuit ){}` or `for (;;) { if( msg.message == WM_QUIT ) return; }`

Comment: @RbMm: It's irrelevant what's inside the `while` loop. A conforming compiler could throw out all code inside the `while` loop, because it can be statically determined, that this code never runs. That was prior to the OP's edit. After the edit, the loop never terminates. This isn't real code.

Comment: @IInspectable - `After the edit, the loop never terminates` - question edited several times, however in all versions loop terminated when `if( msg.message == WM_QUIT ) bQuit = true;`

Comment: @RbMm: The loop never terminated at the time I wrote the comment that the loop never terminated. No need to keep me up to date on a question I have no interest in answering, because we still don't know, whether this is real code or fake code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your error that you call `PeekMessage` only **once** per `WAIT_OBJECT_0` but you need run it in loop `while (::PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ))` because we can have several messages here. and better use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` instead - try this code:

```
bool bQuit = false;
while( !bQuit )// for (;;)
{
    MSG msg;

    switch(::MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx( 0, NULL, 12, QS_ALLINPUT, 0))
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        while (::PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ))
        {
            if( msg.message == WM_QUIT )
                bQuit = true;// return;
            ::TranslateMessage( &msg );
            ::DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        RenderFrame();
        ::SwapBuffers( hDc );
    }
}
```

---

> if I press Alt+F4 to close the window, it does not quit right after I
>   release the key

several messages posted to your thread queue when you press `Alt+F4`, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` return, but you process **not all** it but only **one**

> however, if I hover the mouse over the window, it quits instantly

new messages (`WM_MOUSEMOVE`) placed, but main `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` again return and you at the end process all messages related to close process

Comment: `GetMessage` also does the same right thing?

Comment: @Raindrop7 no of course - we can not use `GetMessage` here, because this is synchronous can can **wait**. we need use **only** `PeekMessage` and in loop while true